# PHP7/mysql PDO custom function

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I'm trying to migrate an application written in **PHP 5.2**, but I'm having trouble creating the correct syntax for custom functions.  This works perfectly in the old syntax, but I get a fatal error with this.

Essentially, I'd like to create a function to make it easy to get an email address from a database table that's associated with a unique id.  I wrote the code below based on what works in PHP 5.2.

```
function getemail($id) {
    $email_query = $con->query("SELECT email FROM admin WHERE id='$id'"); 
    $rs = $email_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $rs;
}
```

Then I could use something like below to call this function.

```
foreach($con->query('SELECT * FROM admin') as $row) {
    echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . ' ' . getemail($row['id']) . '<br>';
}
```

Any direction to help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're referencing `$con` inside of a function, without passing it as a parameter. That's a global no no.

Comment: And performing queries in a loop is a `no-no` too.

Comment: `SELECT email FROM admin WHERE id IN (...)` gets as many specific rows as you want in one query, not N queries.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using prepared statements and supply any user data as separate arguments because you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Comment: Whithin that loop you could simply use `' ' . $row['email'] . '<br>'` :S

Comment: I'm not always querying the admin table when I need to get the email, so I can't always use $row['email']. The 'getemail' function would be used on various pages that have the user's id passed through POST or GET parameter, but I'm trying to use a custom function so I don't have to query the db table every time I need an email address.

Comment: this whole business has absolutely nothing to do with PHP versions. Your code will fail with 5.2 as well. I can't get what is this question about at all. Especially a function to query a database that lets you not to query a database.

Comment: This specific code isn't used in the old version of the script. here's what works in 5.2.       

    `function getemailfromid($userid) {
    $email_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$userid'"); 
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($email_query);
    return $rs['email'];
    }`

Comment: And how do you suppose "not to query the db table every time you need an email address"? Where do you want to get your email from instead?

Comment: Ok, wrong choice of words, I suppose.  I'm trying to write a function that can easily get the email from the table without having to write a query string each and every time. I hope that clarifies my intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have a tool for such a transition, which combines the simplicity of old mysql functions with safety of PDO (if used properly) - [Simple yet efficient PDO wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper)

Having set it up, all you need is a code like this:

```
function getemail($id) {
    return DB::run("SELECT email FROM admin WHERE id=?", [$id])->fetchColumn(); 
}
```

called like this

```
echo getemail(1); // admin@example.com
```